# Auth from different prefix interfering each other

Tags: php, session, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I have two prefix and I set the `AuthComponent` individualy in the `AppController` of the each prefix, the `Auth logic` for each prefix is **completely different**.

Each prefix has a specific `AppController` and all `controllers` of each prefix `extends` the specific `AppController` of the prefix they belongs.

**Here's the problem...** When I loggin on prefix `A` is overriding the `Auth session data` of the prefix `B` so, if I logout on prefix `A` I'm loggin out on prefix `B` too, as I said the prefix are completely different and should'n change override the `session data` of then.

What I need is, when I loggin on one of the prefix it creates the session data in a different `namespace`  or wherever its called from each other.

**AppController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;

class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }


}
```

**AppController from Dashboard prefix**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Dashboard;

use App\Controller\AppController as ParentAppController;


class AppController extends ParentAppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'authDashboard',
                    'userModel' => 'DashboardUsers',
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session'
        ]);
    }

}
```

**AppController from Admin prefix**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\AppController as ParentAppController;


class AppController extends ParentAppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'authAdmin',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session'
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the auth configuration for each AppController?

Comment: Just updated the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, information for both of these logins will be stored in the same area of the session, so one will overwrite the other. You can configure the storage to use different keys:

```
'storage' => ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.Dashboard']
```

vs

```
'storage' => ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.Admin']
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options for details.

Comment: Perfect answer Sir